# Parse Query In Background Sequencing

Tags: parse-platform

What I'm trying to achieve is a populating script for Parse for two tables as following: Table 1 & Table 2

1) I delete everything from Table 1

2) then populate Table 1 using the script.

3) I delete everything from Table 2

4) and populate Table 2 using another script AND a pointer to Table 1 (one to many)

Let's say I have 4 entries for Table 1, then I will have 3 times that amount for Table 2 so it should be 12 entries and each will have a pointer an entry in Table 1.
However, I get 15-21 entries in Table 2 became the deletion in the first step of Table 1 has not been completed by step 4 where I query Table 1 and get the pointer to populate Table 2.

All the deletion/query/insert are done in background. What is one way to synchronize the order of step and do each after the completion of the previous step WITHOUT blocking the main thread?

**EDIT:**
1) PFQuery query for all objects in Table1
2) Delete all objects from query
3) Script to insert PFObjects into Table 1
4) PFQuery query for all objects in Table2
5) Delete all objects from query
6) PFQuery query for all objects in Table1
7) For every object in query, populate Table2 with script and a pointer to the object in Table1

Comment: Can you post some of your code for this? What it sounds like is that you are trying to populate two tables but the population is running on the main thread before your background threads are still running. If you're using objective-c then I can help, I can try with other languages but I'm not as familiar with swift or Android SDK. My suggestion for Objective-C without seeing code is to call [tableView1 reloadData] during the callback of Table1's script and then call [tableView2 reloadData] during the callback of Table2's script

Comment: Do it in the background then? All you have to do is save in background or query find objects in background. In fact most parse related events are non main thread? And your code executes after each block has finished so just put them in order and they will execute accordingly

Comment: the Tables i am referring to are Classes in Parse. It is done in background as of now.

Comment: `What is one way to synchronize the order of step and do each after the completion of the previous step WITHOUT blocking the main thread?`  Trigger the next step in the completion of the first to create a chain of events.

Comment: Thank you so much Logan!!! I didn't know it was possible to add several Objects or delete several objects at once but with your answer, I figured it out. Thank you so much.